# Convert digits into letters

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a javascript project in its basic stage in which the script should prompt the user, ask a digit as input, convert the digit into letters and display it to the user. However the script it not working as it should.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function num()
{
    var arr1=new Array();
    var arr2=new Array();
    var i;
    var start=0;
    var end=start + 1;
    arr1[0]=prompt('Enter Number');
    for (i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        arr2[i]=arr1[0].slice(start, end);
        arr2[i]=parseInt(arr2[i]);
        start++;
        end=start + 1;
        switch(arr2[i])
        {
            case 1:
                document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + 'one';
                break;
            case 2:
                document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + 'two';
                break;
            case 3:
                document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + 'three';
                break;
            case 4:
                document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + 'four';
                break;
            case 5:
                document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + 'five';
                break;
            case 6:
                document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + 'six';
                break;
            case 7:
                document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + 'seven';
                break;
            case 8:
                document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + 'eight';
                break;
            case 9:
                document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + 'nine';
                break;
        }
    }
}
onload=num();
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is a magical operator `+=` that makes your life easier :)

Comment: And you want to change `onload=num();` to `window.onload=num;`

Comment: Define "not working". What it does and what it doesn't?

Comment: why you iterate just 2 times `for (i=0;i<2;i++)`

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks, it works properly now.

Comment: @MilanJaric Actually, right now i have just made a script to accept single digits only. It should have been `for (i=0;i<1;1++)` Don't worry about that.

Comment: @SamarthWahal please mark one of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Particularly, I really don't like `switch` structure. I prefer JavaScript literal object notation.

Check this below:

**html**

`<input type="button" id="getMyNumber" value="Get my Number"/>`

**JavaScript + jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $('#getMyNumber').on('click', function() {
      var numbers = {
          "1": "One",
          "2": "Two",
          "3": "Three",        
          "4": "Four",
          "5": "Five",
          "6": "Six",
          "7": "Seven",
          "8": "Eight",
          "9": "Nine",
          "10": "Ten",
          "default": "No number typed!"
      };
      var input = prompt("Type a number: ");                     
      alert(numbers[input] || numbers["default"]);
   });
});
```

If you prefer, here goes [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsMBW/). No conversion or tricks needed, just simple JavaScript.

**Some references:**

[Mozilla - Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Creating_new_objects)

[The Case against Switch](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/03/08/caseagainstswitch/)

-- EDIT --

Here is the solution with JavaScript only, to avoid the critics (jQuery loading, heavy loading, etc):

**html**

`<input type="button" id="getMyNumber" value="Get my Number" onclick="getNumberRepresentation()" />`

**JavaScript Only**

```
function getNumberRepresentation() {
  var numbers = {
      "1": "One",
      "2": "Two",
      "3": "Three",        
      "4": "Four",
      "5": "Five",
      "6": "Six",
      "7": "Seven",
      "8": "Eight",
      "9": "Nine",
      "10": "Ten",
      "default": "No number typed!"
  };
  var input = prompt("Type a number: ");                     
  alert(numbers[input]);
}
```

Another [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsMBW/2/) version.

Comment: "just simple javascript" backed with a few K of jQuery ;)

Comment: As you want @mplungjan, the EDIT section includes a pure JavaScript version.

Comment: You could also use an array, and if the number isn't in the array then handle "No Number"

Comment: Yeah @TheZ, perfectly. This notation is only my personal choice as I said. There are different ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/WECT8/) Fiddle I made for you.

**EDIT:** Source:

Html:

```
<p onclick="javascript:ask();">Click</p>​
```

Javascript:

```
function ask(){

    var inputAsString;
    var userInput = prompt("Pick a number");

    switch( parseInt(userInput) ){

        case 1:
            inputAsString = "One";
        break;
        case 2:
            inputAsString = "Two";
        break;
        default:
            inputAsString = "I don't know...";           
    }

    alert( "\"" + userInput + "\" as a string is: " + inputAsString );
}​
```

Comment: @Josh, please post your code in the answer. Link only answers are discouraged and usually get flagged for deletion.